# Windows App Certification : Class not registered exception

Tags: windows, wack

When I run the Windows Application Certification Kit I get an exception thats looking like this:

[image]

Well, I got the most recent SDK and installed WACK package (2.2). I cant really tell what could possibly the problem here. Would be great if smo can give me some hints.

Thanks-

Comment: It says "class not registered."  That means that a COM component was not properly registered in the Windows Registry.  It gives you the Class ID, but I don't know how to diagnose it from there.

Comment: The error is not in WACK. It's in your application (as the dialog clearly says in the first sentence, with "has occurred in your application". You need to figure out what Class ID that GUID refers to, and properly register it on your machine. I can't copy and paste it from the image you posted, so I can't search for it on either my machine or via Google, Bing, or MSDN to try and find out what COM class it's trying to instantiate for you.

Comment: That CLSID is for a WACK component, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\App Certification Kit\binaryinfo.dll.  You could try running Regsvr32.exe on it to register it.  Run it from an elevated prompt.  This kind of problem otherwise indicates registry trouble.

Comment: Thanks for all the hints. However I still couldnt solve the problem. Hans, i think your  suggestion could work but there is no binaryinfo.dll file to register